# Memoize a function in parent before passing it to children to avoid rerender React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a chat app, I have 3 main components from parent to child in this hierarchical order: `Chat.js`, `ChatLine.js`, `EditMessage.js`.
I have a function `updateMessage` in `Chat` component that I need to pass to the second child `EditMessage`, but it causes a rerender of every `ChatLine` when I click on `Edit` button and begin typing.
I can't figure out how to memoize it so it only causes a rerender on the `ChatLine` I'm editing.

It only works if I pass it to `ChatLine` as :

```
updateMessage={line.id === editingId ? updateMessage : null}
```

instead of :

```
updateMessage={updateMessage}
```

But I want to avoid that and memoize it instead so it doesn't cause a rerender after each letter I type while editing a message.

This is the whole code: (also available in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-feather-tc8ky) & [Netlify](https://csb-gq65s.netlify.app/))

(Chat.js)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ChatLine from "./ChatLine";

const Chat = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [editValue, setEditValue] = useState("");
  const [editingId, setEditingId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMessages([
      { id: 1, message: "Hello" },
      { id: 2, message: "Hi" },
      { id: 3, message: "Bye" },
      { id: 4, message: "Wait" },
      { id: 5, message: "No" },
      { id: 6, message: "Ok" },
    ]);
  }, []);

  const updateMessage = (editValue, setEditValue, editingId, setEditingId) => {
    const message = editValue;
    const id = editingId;

    // resetting state as soon as we press Enter
    setEditValue("");
    setEditingId(null);

    // ajax call to update message in DB using `message` & `id` variables
    console.log("updating..");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>MESSAGES :</p>
      {messages.map((line) => (
        <ChatLine
          key={line.id}
          line={line}
          editValue={line.id === editingId ? editValue : ""}
          setEditValue={setEditValue}
          editingId={editingId}
          setEditingId={setEditingId}
          updateMessage={updateMessage}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

(ChatLine.js)

```
import EditMessage from "./EditMessage";
import { memo } from "react";

const ChatLine = ({
  line,
  editValue,
  setEditValue,
  editingId,
  setEditingId,
  updateMessage,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {editingId !== line.id ? (
        <>
          <span>{line.id}: </span>
          <span>{line.message}</span>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setEditingId(line.id);
              setEditValue(line.message);
            }}
          >
            EDIT
          </button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <EditMessage
          editValue={editValue}
          setEditValue={setEditValue}
          setEditingId={setEditingId}
          editingId={editingId}
          updateMessage={updateMessage}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(ChatLine);
```

(EditMessage.js)

```
import { memo } from "react";

const EditMessage = ({
  editValue,
  setEditValue,
  editingId,
  setEditingId,
  updateMessage,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        onKeyPress={(e) => {
          if (e.key === "Enter") {
            // prevent textarea default behaviour (line break on Enter)
            e.preventDefault();
            // updating message in DB
            updateMessage(editValue, setEditValue, editingId, setEditingId);
          }
        }}
        onChange={(e) => setEditValue(e.target.value)}
        value={editValue}
        autoFocus
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setEditingId(null);
          setEditValue("");
        }}
      >
        CANCEL
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(EditMessage);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `useCallback` React hook to memoize the `updateMessage` callback so it can be passed as a stable reference. The issue is that each time `Chat` is rendered when `editValue` state updates it is redeclaring the `updateMessage` function so it's a new reference and triggers each child component it's passed to to rerender.

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';
```

...

```
const updateMessage = useCallback(
  (editValue, setEditValue, editingId, setEditingId) => {
    const message = editValue;
    const id = editingId;

    // resetting state as soon as we press Enter
    setEditValue("");
    setEditingId(null);

    // ajax call to update message in DB using `message` & `id` variables
    console.log("updating..");

    // If updating messages state use functional state update to
    // avoid external dependencies.
  },
  []
);
```

[image: Edit memoize-a-function-in-parent-before-passing-it-to-children-to-avoid-rerender-rea]

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I coudn't figure out how to write the function using `useCalback`. I'll get back to the docs to understand it better. Thank you.

Comment: One last question if I may. Is there a way to do the same for `editValue` so I can avoid doing this : `editValue={line.id === editingId ? editValue : ""}`, and instead just pass it normally as `editValue={editValue}` to `ChatLine` without it causing rerenders while typing in the textarea field?

Comment: @dwix I didn't notice anything rerendering (*other than the active `ChatLine` component by line id*) while updating the textarea. What are you seeing rerendering? Which component?

Comment: I'm using ReactDevtool Profiler and I see every line rerenders with each letter typed in the input. Your solution for `updateMessage` worked well, but now I'm asking about the `editValue` I'm passing from the parent component `Chat` to its child `ChatLine`, for now I'm passing it as `editValue={line.id === editingId ? editValue : ""}` to avoid the excessive rerendering, I'd like to pass it just as `editValue={editValue}` if there's a solution like you did for `updateMessage`.

Comment: and here is updated CodeSandbox & Netlify links if you can check it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-surf-rlti0  And https://csb-rlti0.netlify.app/  When I click on `Edit` button and start typing, `Chat` rerenders which is normal, but also every `ChatLine` even the ones not being edited, because I'm passing the prop as `editValue={editValue}` this time.

Comment: @dwix If you take another look in the CSB I linked there's an `useEffect` in `ChatLine` that logs `console.log("ChatLine rendered", { id: line.id });` when it renders. When edit mode is toggled for a specific chat line and text area is being edited, there are only logs for the chat line being edited. I don't know what you are seeing in the profiler, but not every `ChatLine` is be rerendered when 1 of them is being edited. The reason is because while this is occurring `line.id === editingId ? editValue : ""` doesn't change value until you hit enter or cancel the edit mode.

Comment: I added a console.log() in `ChatLine` and it gets printed 6 times on each letter typed, I'm refering to the last CodeSandbox I've linked "https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-surf-rlti0?file=/src/components/Chat.js" , because I'm passing the prop as `editValue={editValue}` from `Chat` to `ChatLine`, I was wondering if there's a way to leave the prop passed that way instead of `editValue={line.id === editingId ? editValue : ""}` while also avoiding the rerendering problem, maybe a solution like you did for `updateMessage`. Please use the last CodeSandbox link to see what I see, Thank you.

Comment: @dwix [1]When you pass the same `editValue` to each `ChatLine` then they all see, and rerender, when the value changes. ***BUT*** when you pass `editValue={line.id === editingId ? editValue : ""}` *only* the `ChatLine` with the matching id sees when `editValue` changes, the rest are passed `""` and strings are ***always*** equal to themselves, it's one of their "primitive"-esque properties. Now, you may be able to do is also pass the `editingId` value as a prop and wrap each `ChatLine` in the `memo` HOC and provide a custom `areEqual` function to hint to React it doesn't need to rerender.

Comment: @dwix [2] Here is a link to [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo). The `areEqual` function should compare the `line.id` prop value to the `editingId` value, but this all might be a bit confusing to use here, and quite frankly really easy to mess up. IMHO using `editValue={line.id === editingId ? editValue : ""}` is much easier to read and understand than adding in the additional HOC and equality function.

Comment: I understand, thank you!